# Choosing gcc Compiler for 64-bit arm design

Tags: gcc, arm, 32bit-64bit, armv8

I have been doing some bare metal programming in 32-bit iMX6q SABRE-SD board(arm Cortex-A9). I have used "arm-none-eabi" as the Toolchain. Now, I would like to port all the codes i have written to 64-bit arm Cortex-A57 (R-Car M3 board).  How would i select the compiler for this task. Can i use the same compiler with some flag changes for compiling for 64-bit design. Or Will there be any specific compiler provided by the manufacturer.

How would someone select the compiler for his/her embedded design.

Please Help.

Regards,

Ajmal

Comment: You probably need gcc for the aarch64 architecture.

Comment: you want the aarch64-none-elf (or whatever the rest of the triplet is if it eve matters).  I am trying to figure out if it can do aarch32 or if you have to use two compilers one for the aarch64 bit instruction set then if you switch to aarch32 if you have to use a different toolchain.  --target-help does not show any architectures, but the options show 32 bit instruction set flags

Comment: gcc in general is a build a new copy of the toolchain per target design, where llvm/clang is build one toolchain for all targets (other than linking) kind of a design.  and with aarch64 gnu appears to require a toolchain build.

Answer (score 0):

For compiling into 64-bit architecture, linaro gcc tool could be used:
Please refer to this link:
https://community.arm.com/dev-platforms/f/discussions/5274/issue-compiling-armv8-assembly